# Azure DevOps nightly build - schedules \ cron syntax

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set my nightly build to occur at 00:30 every day in my build pipeline YAML file.
I get the following error when trying to build:

> `Improperly formed cron syntax: '00 30 00 * * *'`

This is what I've tried:

```
schedules:
- cron: '00 30 00 * * *'
```

and I have tried:

```
schedules:
- cron: '0 30 0 * * *'
```

I am checking my work against the following [tool](http://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=00+30+00+*+*+*&locale=en) (not totally sure if the tool is perfect though).

Microsoft Doc: [azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#scheduled-trigger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Double-quotes instead of single-quotes (?)
2. Five cron fields, not six

[Two examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers):

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
    exclude:
    - releases/ancient/*
- cron: "0 12 * * 0"
  displayName: Weekly Sunday build
  branches:
    include:
    - releases/*
  always: true
```

For simple reference, each cron expression represents a space-delimited expression with five entries in the following order:

```
mm HH DD MM DW
 \  \  \  \  \__ Days of week
  \  \  \  \____ Months
   \  \  \______ Days
    \  \________ Hours
     \__________ Minutes
```

So, example build at 00:30 every day:

```
schedules:
- cron: "30 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily 00:30 build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
    exclude:
    - releases/ancient/*
```

Cron descriptor link cross-check:

[http://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=30+0+*+*+*&locale=en](http://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=30%200%20*%20*%20*&locale=en)

Comment: Just tried, double quotes still result in the same error: `Error while validating cron input. Improperly formed cron syntax: '00 31 00 * * *'.` (changed the time to ensure my change was being seen in the web ui)

Comment: @BrienFoss I think it may be the extra asterisk then (should be five fields total)

Comment: thank you! I removed the initial `0` as shown in your example above.